# Can't change date of Remote File - FTP

Tags: delphi, ftp, chilkat

I need to change the date of the remote file via Chilkat's FTP Component.
I have used  CkFtp2_getAutoFeat(pFtpClient) so as to activate the features of the server.

```
wDate:='Mon, 20 Oct 2016 16:35:00 -0500' 
CkFtp2_SetRemoteFileDateTimeStr(pFtpClient,pWideChar(wDate),pWideChar(wHostFileName)) ;
```

Gives Error

```
'<ChilkatLog>'#$D#$A'<SetRemoteFileDateTime>'#$D#$A'<DllDate>Dec 13 2012</DllDate>'#$D#$A'<UnlockPrefix>xxxxxx</UnlockPrefix>'#$D#$A'<Username>VMAF:user</Username>'#$D#$A'<Architecture>Little Endian; 32-bit</Architecture>'#$D#$A'<Language>C++ Builder XE2</Language>'#$D#$A'<VerboseLogging>0</VerboseLogging>'#$D#$A'<DateTime>Thu, 20 Oct 2016 21:35:00 GMT</DateTime>'#$D#$A'<info>Trying MDTM...</info>'#$D#$A'<info>Trying SITE UTIME...</info>'#$D#$A'<error>Failed.</error>'#$D#$A'</SetRemoteFileDateTime>'#$D#$A'</ChilkatLog>'#$D#$A
```

With another delphi component (TFTPClient from ICS) the date changes using same server.

I am using an older Chilkat Dll version as I am comfortable with that and all works fine except the date change.

I am using Delphi Dll, Chilkat Ftp2, ICS TFTPServer component, Windows OS

Regards

Comment: The log you provided shows a `SITE UTIME` command being sent and fails. ICS's `TFtpClient` and `TFtpServer` do not implement `SITE UTIME` at all, they only support `MFMT` and `MDTM` instead (`TFtpServer` supports both. `TFtpClient` sends either one depending on server capabilities)

Comment: In the error there is Trying MDTM ..  first and then Trying SITE UTIME.

Comment: but the log doesn't show which format of MTDM it tries, or what the result was. I also see `VerboseLogging` is 0, can you enable more detailed logging? Will it then log the *actual* commands and replies being exchanged?

Comment: I made verbose logging true but the message did not change at all, except VerboseLoggin became 1

Comment: Why are you passing the string parameters as `PWideChar` when the function is [declared](https://github.com/chilkatsoft/Chilkat-PHP-Extension/blob/master/chilkat/ChilkatLib/Package/include/C_CkFtp2.h) to use `char*` (`PAnsiChar` in Delphi) instead? Do you have the same problem if you use `CkFtp2_SetRemoteFileDateTime()` or `CkFtp2_SetRemoteFileDt()` instead?

Comment: Same Error
`wSetFeat:=CkFtp2__Feat(pFtpClient) ;  
// Returns '211-Extensions supported:  HOST  SIZE  REST STREAM  MDTM  MDTM YYYYMMDDHHMMSS[+-TZ] filename  MLST size*;type*;perm*;create*;modify*;  MFMT  MD5  XCRC "filename" start end  XMD5 "filename" start end  CLNT  SITE INDEX;ZONE;MSG;EXEC;PSWD;CMLSD;DMLSD  XCMLSD  XDMLSD 211 END'  
wDate:='Tue, 30 Oct 2016 16:43:00 +0530' ;  
DtTm:=CkDateTime_Create() ;  
CkDateTime_SetFromRfc822(DtTm,pWideChar(wDate)) ; // Returns True  
CkFtp2_SetRemoteFileDt(pFtpClient,DtTm ,pWideChar(wHostFileName)) ;  
CkDateTime_Dispose(DtTm) ;`